# constexpr char array with GCC and clang

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class const_string {
public:
    template <std::size_t sz>
    constexpr const_string(const char (&str)[sz]): p_(str) {}
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t i) const { return p_[i]; }
private:
    const char* p_;
};

template <char c>
void Print() { std::cout << c << '\n'; }

int main() {
    constexpr char str[] = "Hello World";
    Print<const_string(str)[0]>();
}
```

It compiles fine with clang, while GCC gives the following error message:

`in constexpr expansion of 'const_string((* & str)).const_string::operator[](0ul)'
error: '(const char*)(& str)' is not a constant expression`

However, if I change `Print<const_string(str)[0]>();` to `Print<const_string("Hello World")[0]>();`. Both clang and GCC compile fine.

What is going on here? Which compiler is correct according to the standard?

Comment: [Compiles in head](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6ZD0KzdJZHj9VljA) (and the most recent version, 5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65642) and appears to compile on gcc 5 as shown [here](http://goo.gl/3z2gOr).